# Is there an equivalent of Flask's `@app.errorhandler` in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm writing several views, and would like to validate the request bodies. The common case is that the body must be a JSON object with certain keys present. I wrote one view, and have this code:

```
try:
    body = json.loads(request.body)
except ValueError:
    return InvalidInputResponse("Could not load request body")

if not isinstance(body, dict):
    return InvalidInputResponse("Request body was not a JSON object")

if set(body.keys()) != {'author', 'title', 'content'}:
    return InvalidInputResponse("Request object missing keys")
```

`InvalidInputResponse` is a subclass of `http.HttpResponse`.

I'd like to re-use this code in other views. What I really want to do is this:

```
body = process_body(request.body, required_keys={'author', 'title', 'content'})
# rest of code here ...
```

However, as the code is now, I can't do this. I'd have to do:

```
body = process_body(request.body, required_keys={'author', 'title', 'content'})
if isinstance(body, http.HttpResponse):
    return body
# rest of code here ...
```

This is a bit ugly.

In Flask, I could create a custom exception, called `InvalidInputException`, and then [register an error handler for it](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/apierrors/)... say, something like:

```
@app.errorhandler(InvalidInputException)
def handle_invalid_input(error):
    return InvalidInputResponse(error.reason)
```

Is there an equivalent mechanism in Django? If there's no equivalent mechanism, what's the equivalent way to handle this?

Comment: A similar path is possible in Django. Write a custom middleware with a [`process_exception()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/#process_exception) handler. Either attach globally or via [`decorator_from_middleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.decorators.decorator_from_middleware)

Answer (score 3):

Django has custom exception handlers, too. They can be attached [via middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/#process_exception).

```
class InvalidInputMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, InvalidInputException):
             return InvalidInputResponse(exception.reason)

        return None
```

Django will return the first response returned by any middleware. Note that the response phase runs middlewares in reverse order.

If used globally, just add to the end of [`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware). For the non-global case, I use a (slightly evil) `middleware_on_class` monkey-patcher that does the job:

```
from functools import wraps
from django.utils.decorators import (
    decorator_from_middleware,
    method_decorator
)

def middleware_on_class(middleware):
    def decorator(cls):
        dispatch = cls.dispatch

        @wraps(dispatch)
        @method_decorator(decorator_from_middleware(middleware))
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs)

        cls.dispatch = wrapper
        return cls
    return decorator
```

Use as

```
handle_invalid_input = middleware_on_class(InvalidInputMiddleware)

@handle_invalid_input
class View(...):
    pass
```

Comment: Ah alright! I understand the global approach. Can you explain how I'd use `middleware_on_class`? I'm not familiar enough with Django to see how to apply it.

Comment: @Claudiu Added. Note that this is my typical use case, YMMV.